# How to do multiple partial online refunds?

Tags: creditmemo, magento2.2.0, refund, partial-invoice

I am trying to perform online partial refund on **Magento 2.2.0**, but once I press on `creditmemo` button in invoice page, and first partial refund is performed, you cannot perform another partial refunds after first one, because `credit memo` button will not appear anymore.

I traced the issue, and found that there is `is_used_for_refund` column inside the invoice table, that is set to 1 and prevent other partial refunds from taking place,

I am asking is it possible to issue partial refunds multiple times in Magento2? if yes, how can I enable that?

Comment: Which payment method?

Comment: I am using custom payment method that I developed using this tutorial https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-create-payment-method/

Comment: @ZeidAl-Rashwani did you got any solution?

Comment: @DeebanBabu unfortunately, no